# How can you return a default value instead of a key error when accessing a multi-dimenional dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a value out of a multi-dimensional dictionary, which looks for example like this:

```
count = {'animals': {'dogs': {'chihuahua': 23}}
```

So if i want to know how much chihuahua's i got, i'm printing `count['animals']['dogs']['chihuahua']`

But i want to access `count['vehicles']['cars']['vw golf']` too, and instead of key errors i want to return 0.

actually i'm doing this:

```
if not 'vehicles' in count:
    count['vehicles'] = {}
if not 'cars' in count['vehicles']:
    count['vehicles']['cars'] = {}
if not 'vw golf' in count['vehicles']['cars']['vw golf']:
    count['vehicles']['cars']['vw golf'] = 0
```

How can i do this better?

I'm thinking of some type of class which inherits from dict, but that's just an idea.

Comment: [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
return count.get('vehicles', {}).get('cars', {}).get('vw golf', 0)
```

basically, return an empty dictionary if not found, and get the count at the end.

This would work assuming the dataset is in the specified format only. It would not raise errors, however you might have to tweak it for other datatypes

Demo

```
>>> count = {'animals': {'dogs': {'chihuahua': 23}}}
>>> count.get('vehicles', {}).get('cars', {}).get('vw golf', 0)
0
>>> count = {'vehicles': {'cars': {'vw golf': 100}}}
>>> count.get('vehicles', {}).get('cars', {}).get('vw golf', 0)
100
>>>
```

Comment: Simply Awesome, never thought it would be _that_ easy.

Comment: I have never doubted :)

Comment: So how would you add `bikes` to the `vehicles` category at an arbitrary point in the program without doing an explicit check whether `count['vehicles']` exists?

Comment: The question was about retrieving values, and I explicitly mentioned that this would have to be tweaked for other usecases. @LukasGraf

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(Counter))
```

Usage:

```
>>> counts['animals']['dogs']['chihuahua'] = 23
>>> counts['vehicles']['cars']['vw golf'] = 100
>>>
>>> counts['animals']['dogs']['chihuahua']
23
>>> # No fancy cars yet, Counter defaults to 0
... counts['vehicles']['cars']['porsche']
0
>>>
>>> # No bikes yet, empty counter
... counts['vehicles']['bikes']
Counter()
```

The [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) in the construction of the `defaultdict` is needed because `defaultdict` expects a factory. So `lambda: defaultdict(Counter)` basically creates a function that will return `defaultdict(Counter)` when called - which is what's required to create the multi-dimensional dictionary you described:

A dictionary whose values default to a dictionary whose values default to an instance of `Counter`.

The advantage of this solution is that you don't have to keep track of which categories you already defined. You can simply assign two new categories and a new count in one go, and use the same syntax to add a new count for existing categories:

```
>>> counts['food']['fruit']['bananas'] = 42
>>> counts['food']['fruit']['apples'] = 3
```

*(This assumes that you'll always want exactly three dimensions to your data structure, the first two being category dictionaries and the third being a `Counter` where the actual counts of things will be stored).*